# How to extract data from a raw file with Python

Tags: python, regex

Current code:

```
import re 

file = open("d.txt", "rb")
regex = r'((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:'\
         '25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:'\
         '25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:'\
         '25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?))'\
         '\.+([^\.]+)\.+([^\.]+)'

for x in (re.findall(regex, file)):
    print("\t".join(x))
```

I want to extract data from a raw file and print it to the screen

the raw output is written to a file with the script below:

```
data=r.raw.read()
        if "var fgt_lang =" in str(data):
            with open("logs.dat", 'w') as f:
                f.write(data)
```

The raw file is a huge file to sort through and includes sample data like in the below format:

```
..........460000...........192.168.11.27....Germany..............hasdy2348a@sd
..........blah.....blah.............192.168.11.19.........................Swed
en..........................................................................Tw
inkle009................blah.................
```

How can I be able to extract and print out the data in the following format:

```
192.168.11.27  Germany  hasdy2348a@sd
192.168.11.19  Sweden   Twinkle009
```

My best guess was to use regex patterns and this is where am stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be hard to come up with a regular expression or other solution with the sample data you've provided.  Can you post something more realistic or perhaps more info about the format of your data?

Comment: Strange raw file!!! are you sure that you've shown us the exact data inside that raw file?

Comment: @Peymanmohsenikiasari It's just the sample of the actual data. too bad i can't paste it all here. I have updated the OP with the code that creates the raw file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed regex is a the way to go:

```
import re 

data = "..........460000...........192.168.11.27....Germany..............hasdy2348a@sd..........blah.....blah.............192.168.11.19.........................Sweden..........................................................................Twinkle009................blah................."


regex = r'((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:'\
         '25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:'\
         '25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:'\
         '25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?))'\
         '\.+([^\.]+)\.+([^\.]+)'

for r in (re.findall(regex, data)):
  print("\t".join(r))
```

Comment: You just made my day. Thanks mate

Comment: How do you read it from a file? am getting TypeError: expected string or buffer when i use file =open("d.txt", "rb")

Comment: same results. is there a way i can share the raw file with you?

Comment: I have uploaded the file here https://fs13n4.sendspace.com/dl/b554ec7e9889fbad82a027fd6655c752/5d607bdd690f073d/47uw32/log.txt

Try to see if you can recreate the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can go with a Regex like this:

```
(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)\.*([^.]*)\.*([^.]*)
```

The first capture is for the IP address (for a better way of capturing IP addresses see [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html)). For the other two captures, I assumed anything except a dot can go.

Comment: Thanks, however there are 3 items i want to print on the same line at the time as I read through the file. IP, Country and code. How do i extract all three items?

Comment: The Regex above has three capturing groups (parts that start and end with parantheses), so it extracts all 3 of them. Check [here](http://regexr.com/4jone)